# Cube Emitter: the cubes emitted pass through the ground plane instead of rest on it

Tags: animation, rigid-body-simulation

I would like to animate a great number of Cubes, falling from a surface at a determined height one after the other. The problem is that in doing this, the cubes emitted pass through the ground plane instead of stick on it. Also I would translate this surface, in order to create a sort-kind of grid with the falling cubes.

Has someone a tip how to do it? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This answer is just regarding your ground plain and having objects stick to it. I am assuming that this is a particle system. For your ground plane will need to have:

1. A collision modifier added, then
2. In the physics field to make them "stick" an option is that you could set Damping to 1 and Friction to 1. However, play around with the fields.

Note, this image is just using default particles with no mods.

[image]

After downloading your blend file I did the same and it worked as expected. Again noting this is only the getting the cube to 'stick' the other part is a bit vague for me.

[image]

Comment: I've just uploaded the .blend